# Error:(12, 23) java: package org.apache.http does not exist

Tags: android, android-apache-legacy

my android project doesn't contain build.gradle to put `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`

[image]

Comment: click on the project button as seen in the image, you'll have option to switch to 'android' there. Then you can see the gradle scripts

Comment: which IDE are you using? eclipse or Android studio?

Comment: API 23 removed that library. You probably need to compile with a lower Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Sample.App"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            renderscriptDebuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
}
```

[image]